# XNA Shader working different on different PC's

Tags: xna

I am working on a game in C#/XNA which uses custom shaders for drawing. When the code is compiled on my machine it works perfectly on all computers I tested, but when my team member tries to compile it locally, there are very weird visual artifacts. The walls of our maze are stretched to what looks to be infinity based on that they seem to end at the far plane of the game camera.

We both use visual studio 2013 with XNA game studio 4 and we can't find any differences in our build settings (which should come from our git repository anyway). We also tried copying our code files directly from one computer to another, but it resulted in the same.

Now we are totally lost in what to do next. Any ideas what it could be?

```
float4x4 mvp_matrix;    // = model * view * projection
Texture2D tex;

SamplerState MeshTextureSampler
{
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    AddressU = Wrap;
    AddressV = Wrap;
};

struct VS_INPUT
{
    float3 Position : POSITION0;
    float3 Normal   : NORMAL0;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Position : POSITION0;
    float3 Normal   : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD1;
};

VS_OUTPUT VertexShaderFunction(VS_INPUT input)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;

    output.Position = mul(float4(input.Position, 1), mvp_matrix);
    output.Normal = input.Normal;
    output.TexCoord = input.TexCoord;

    return output;
}

float4 PixelShaderFunction(VS_OUTPUT input) : COLOR0
{
    return float4(tex.Sample(MeshTextureSampler, input.TexCoord).rgb, 1);
}

technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderFunction();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
```

This is our simple shader variant (Both possible shaders have the problem)

[image]
Working maze on my PC

[image]
Broken maze on their PC

Note that the compiled version works on all the PC's, so I don't think it's probable that it's a problem on the GPU-side.

Comment: Try compiling on your computer and having your team member run it. Does the same problem arise?

Comment: No, as stated: when compiling will give you a working version, the version will work on all pc's.

Comment: Could he be compiling it under different settings? like the wrong shader model?